# Importin dll in Python on Linux

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

Hello I have this code that runs perfectly on Windows:

```
    import ctypes
    import sys
    import os
    from ctypes import *
    from numpy import *
    import time
    from ctypes.util import find_library
    libEDK = cdll.LoadLibrary("edk.dll")
```

I try running this on Ubuntu and I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/nassar/Downloads/python/sds.py", line 9, in <module> 
   libEDK = cdll.LoadLibrary("/home/nassar/Desktop/python/edk.dll")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/nassar/Desktop/python/edk.dll: invalid ELF header
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

er... you can't do that;

Shared libraries are very OS dependent, so a library built for windows cannot possibly work in linux, or visa versa.

Except that you *might* get some luck with [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/), which is a Windows runtime which works across many platforms.  I have certainly had some success running Python binaries within wine.

Comment: Did you ever test the WINE idea? I seriously doubt you can instrument WINE to load a windows DLL from Python on a *nix System. Unless you run everything, including Python, on WINE - in which case the original code can / must be used.

Comment: @lukas: yes, exactly, you must run a windows version of python within wine.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, we have something called `shared object` (.so) instead of DLL's.

Long story short: you can't load a Windows DLL on a Linux system. You need to compile a Linux shared library ("edk.so").

Comment: any clue to start where? To compile it into .so ?