# Using .NET Core Library in Linux Python

Tags: c#, python, linux, .net-core

I wrote a C# library in linux with .NET Core. Now I want to use it in python. Has someone experience with this topic? Is this even possible?

I tried to use

```
import ctypes as ct
lib = ct.WinDLL("PythonTest.dll")
```

but I run in this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WinDLL'
```

Comment: i was able to import WinDLL,  are you sure that you are giving the full path to the pythontest.dll?

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries)

> On Linux, it is required to specify the filename including the extension to load a library, so attribute access can not be used to load libraries. Either the LoadLibrary() method of the dll loaders should be used, or you should load the library by creating an instance of CDLL by calling the constructor:

`WinDLL()` is for Windows  on Linux you need to use `.LoadLibrary()` or `CDLL()`

Comment: Thanks for your question. But now I run into the error "invalid ELF header".

Comment: @Christian Ah I was hoping you had found a way around that.  Have you seen:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762142/importin-dll-in-python-on-linux